# Selenium webdriver python find element by xpath - Could not find element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I m trying to write a script with selenium webdriver python.
When I try to do a

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='posted_1']/div[3]")
```

it says

> NoElementFoundException.

Can someone please help me here?

Regards
Bala

Comment: we need more information from you. What's the website for example?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be you are locating with incorrect locator, So you need to share HTML for better locator solution.
- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

  element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='posted_1']/div[3]")))
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  driver.switch_to_frame("frame/iframe I'd or name")

  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

  element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='posted_1']/div[3]")))

  #Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switch_to_default_content();
  ```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, but after implementing your suggestion this is what I get to see in the output. 0.00s   [INFO]  Starting measurement [160824_FW_3QJW]
0.36s   [INFO]  Executing WebDriver script
20.76s  [ERROR] TimeoutException: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
Line 34, in <synthetic script>
 element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='posted_1']/div[3]")))
Line 80, in until
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: If your xpath is correct then make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe... if it is then consider third provided point...:)

Comment: Hi Saurbah, yes i checked the xpath. Just to be safe - tried the find element by name for the same attribute but still getting the same error.This is the actual element. <input name="searchBox" placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="text" ng-model="search.keyword" on-enter-key="doSuperSearch(search.keyword)" ng-blur="onSearchBlur()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" style="">

Comment: This is what I put in my script. wait = driver.implicitly_wait(10)

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "searchBox")))

Comment: This is the output I got.

0.00s   [INFO]  Starting measurement [160825_5F_11V]
0.38s   [INFO]  Executing WebDriver script
11.32s  [ERROR] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'until'
Traceback (most recent call last):
Line 34, in <synthetic script>
 element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "searchBox")))

Comment: Actually you're implementing wrong, it should be `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "searchBox")))`

Comment: You need to Initialize `WebDriverWait` instead of `implicitly_wait` as `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` then use `wait.until()`..see the provided answer carefully...:)

Comment: Hi,

I tried locating a id as well as it was more straightforward. Below is the error I got after implementing it.

26.23s  [ERROR] TimeoutException: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
Line 34, in <synthetic script>
 element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'paymentButton')))
Line 80, in until
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: Below is the HTML source

<button ng-click="$state.go('main.payment.create', {fromAccount: defaultFromAccount})" id="paymentButton" class="btn btn-floating-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle=""><div ng-show="!hidePlus" class="more animated"><i class="icon-plus"></i></div><div ng-show="hidePlus" class="pay animated ng-hide" style=""><i class="icon-usd"></i></div></button>


Can you please help/suggest?

Answer (score 0):

that exception, unsurprisingly, means that that element wasn't available on the DOM.  There are a couple of options here:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

will tell the driver to wait 10 seconds (or any amount of time) after an element is not found/not clickable etc., and tries again after.  Sometimes elements don't load right away, so an implicit wait fixes those types of problems.

The other option here is to do an explicit wait.  This will wait until the element appears, and until the existence of that element is confirmed, the script will not move on to the next line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='posted_1']/div[3]")))
```

In my experience, an implicit wait is usually fine, but imprecise.